# M is undefined when initializing Materializecss Meteor

Tags: reactjs, meteor, materialize

I am using Materialize Release: 1.0.0-alpha.4 with meteor v1.6, I installed via atmospherejs with

`meteor add materialize:materialize`

Now everything is working fine but when initializing things like modals, dropdowns and anything else if I don't use jQuery it doesn't work, I don't want to use jQuery, because I am using react, the error I get is M is not defined when I try to initialize it like this

```
var elem = document.querySelector('select');
var instance = M.FormSelect.getInstance(elem);
```

Is there a better way I can make it work without jQuery or is there a way of importing M as part of Materialize or could it be that the meteor package isn't using the latest version of Materialize as it seems to be.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the documentation is out of date. A little digging and I found the the `FormSelect` method is now just `Select`. To get a new instance I used the `new` keyword instead of calling `init`. Here is the code that worked for me.

`var selectInput = document.querySelectorAll('select');
selectInput.forEach((el) => new M.Select(el, {}));`